# Equinox OSGi + JavaFX resolving dependency

Tags: java, javafx, dependencies, osgi, equinox

i am trying now for 2 days to solve this equinox problem :)

My Goal: I want to create an osgi based JavaFX UI Application

What I have done so far:

1) Created a target runtime in Eclipse based on this steps:

- Open Preferences > Plugin-in Development > Target Platform
- Click Add ...
- Select "Nothing: Start with an empty target definition".
- Add ...
- Select Software Site
     Add ​http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/runtime-nightly/site or http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/runtime-released/1.2.0/site
  as a site.
- Expand "FX Target" and check "Target Platform for Eclipse" UND the "Minimal JavaFX Osgi integration bundle" and uncheck "Include required software"
- Finish and activate the new target.

2) Then I created with New -> Project -> JavaFX -> OSGI an OSGi Application Project

3) Hit Run - WORKED yes :)

4) My next goal was i wanted an standalone application without launching eclipse

5) I exported my Application as an deployable plugin

6) Created a new dir with just the org.eclipse.osgi_3.2.0.jar and my app jar in it

7) Run: java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.2.0.jar -console

8) Entered Command: install file:app.jar

9) diag 1

10) 4 unresolved dependency (fx osgi equinox stuff etc.)

Until this point i thought i was on the right way.
I can understand that my App needs those required packages to get the status "resolved". So I thought i could manually download the jar files via the internet.. and guess every package brought new dependencies :P

Then i found out that there is a features function to export all need packages with eclipse so i got an export, consisting of theses files:

```
features\
plugins\
JFXTest.app_1.0.0.201506291019.jar
org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.5.0.v20150421-2214.jar
org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_1.5.0.v20150422-0725.jar
org.eclipse.core.databinding.property_1.5.0.v20150422-0725.jar
org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.5.0.v20150422-0725.jar
org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.7.0.v20150330-2103.jar
org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.11.0.v20150405-1723.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.300.v20150423-1356.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.7.0.v20150402-1709.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.300.v20150423-1356.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.3.100.v20140115-1647.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.5.300.v20150408-1437.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.6.0.v20150318-1503.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.500.v20130404-1337.jar
org.eclipse.fx.core.databinding_2.1.0.201506281929.jar
org.eclipse.fx.javafx_2.2.0.201506281924.jar
org.eclipse.fx.osgi_2.1.0.201506281924.jar
org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.5.0.v20150519-2006.jar
org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.100.v20150529-1857.jar
artifacts.jar
content.jar
```

Sooo now my questions :)

1) How do I install all of them without typing in every dependency jar or is in general my idea totally wrong ;)

2) Is there a way that the OSGi jar file loads all the stuff he needs from an offical online repository or something similar to it?

3) In case i want to use my Application as standalone i dont want to type all the osgi commands etc. i found out that there is the possibility to use a launcher (which also need dependencis, how to resolve?) and the eclipse.exe
And here i do have an understanding issue: It is not clear to me were there border is between eclipse and the osgi implementation equinox.

Thanks a lot
and greetings from Germany

CheVeyo

Answer (score 0):

[image: Eclipse Screenshot of an OSGi Application Project]

I tried to make some progress today by myself. I found the "Export Product" Function in Eclipse but all the time i try to export it, it keeps complaining that a certain bundle is missing. But as far i can see it, it is listed under the Plugin Dependency with a certain path.

Can someone bring some light into it :P I mean it cant be so difficult to fix a standard eclipse project^^

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question by myself.
Obviously in the feature.xml where a few lines missing:

```
    <plugin id="org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util" install-size="0" version="0.0.0" unpack="false" />
    <plugin id="org.eclipse.fx.ui.databinding" install-size="0" version="0.0.0" unpack="false" />
    <plugin id="org.eclipse.fx.core" install-size="0" version="0.0.0" unpack="false" />
    <plugin id="javax.inject" install-size="0" version="0.0.0" unpack="false" />
    <plugin id="org.apache.commons.lang" install-size="0" version="0.0.0" unpack="false" />
```

After adding them it worked fine and i got an eclipse and repository dir.
In the next step i downloaded the launcher from this location:
http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/equinox/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/index.php
and unpacked it in the previously created eclipse dir and then i started eclipse.exe (dont overwrite anything!)

But i think there must be a bug in the standard eclipse project for OSGI based Applications!

I leave this Thread open for further disscusion